# ImportError: cannot import name cached_property

Tags: python, google-app-engine, tipfy

I am trying to set up Tipfy extensions on a Python/Google App Engine project that I've been brought in on. I have followed all the instructions for running bootstrap.py and then bin/buildout. Everything seems to have worked but now when I try to import tipfy.ext.auth, I get this error:

```
File "C:\{project}\app\lib\dist\tipfy\ext\auth\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tipfy import abort, cached_property, import_string, redirect
ImportError: cannot import name cached_property
```

I'm a bit lost now and don't really know where to even look for the solution to this as I am, admittedly, very new to both Python and GAE. Any help or direction on how to get this extension working would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Potential solution here: http://tipfy.googlecode.com/hg/docs/source/guide/migrating.rst Remove that import and import from werkzeug instead.

Comment: I am not sure if you should be using tipfy, unless it is a requirement. Nobody is maintaining it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potential solution here: http://tipfy.googlecode.com/hg/docs/source/guide/migrating.rst
tl;dr: Remove that import and import from werkzeug instead.